Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@61094d90
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file C:\Users\ASUS\AndroidStudioProjects\Algoritma_3\app\build\intermediates\incremental\debug\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@61094d90.). Check logs for more details.

helped me justify my project
